# boundary of an bidisc as a disjoint union

Tags: complex-analysis, several-complex-variables

I found in "Several complex variables" by Jaap Korevaar and Jan Wiegnerick ([https://www.math.stonybrook.edu/~ebedford/PapersForM537/WiegerinckKorevaar.pdf](https://www.math.stonybrook.edu/%7Eebedford/PapersForM537/WiegerinckKorevaar.pdf)) in Chapter 1.2 that the boundary of a bidisc centered at $a = (0,0) = 0$ is defined as the *disjoint union*
$$ \{ C(0,r_1) \times \Delta(0,r_2) \} \ \cup \ \{ \Delta(0,r_1) \times C(0,r_2) \} \ \cup \ \{ C(0,r_1) \times C(0,r_2) \} $$,

where $\Delta(0,r_j) = \{z \in \mathbb C^2 : |z_j| < r_j, \ j=1,2\} $ are the discs and $C(0,r_j) = \{z \in \mathbb C^2 : |z_j| = r_j, \ j=1,2\} $ are the circles. The bidisc with polyradius $r = (r_1, r_2)$ is then $\Delta(0,r) = \Delta(0,r_1) \times \Delta(0,r_2)$.

My first question is: Why do we need for the boundary the parts $\{ C(0,r_1) \times \Delta(0,r_2) \}$ and $\{ \Delta(0,r_1) \times C(0,r_2) \}$ ? Why isn't $\{ C(0,r_1) \times C(0,r_2) \}$ enough for the boundary? Since in 1D complex space (2D real space), the boundary of a disc is precisely the circle "around" it.

Second question: What exactly is it meant with the *disjoint union*? From the definition of a disjoint union, for example from Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint_union) it has to do something with indexing from which set the value comes (as far as I understand)

Comment: Disjoint union just means taking the union but treating them as seperate (e.g. you could disjoimt union an object with itself and get two copies instead of one). When sets are already disjoint, the disjoint union is just a union.

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen okay, now I get it.. Thanks! Do you maybe have an answer for my first question?

Comment: For the first question, by definition we have $\partial (A \times B) = (\partial A \times B) \cup (A \times \partial B) $ for any manifolds with boundary $A, B$. In this case we have that $A = C(0,r_1) \cup \Delta(0,r_1) $ and $B = C(0,r_2) \cup \Delta(0,r_2)$ (where these unions are disjoint, with the former the boundary of the latter in each case) so $\partial A = C(0,r_1)$ and $\partial B = C(0,r_2)$ so the formula given by the author follows.

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen but why do you need to include $\Delta(0,r_1)$ for the boundary of $A$, i.e. $\Delta(0,r_2)$ for the boundary of $B$ ? Isn't the circle the boundary?

Comment: For the first question, you can start inside the bidisc at the origin $(0, 0)$ and move along the $z_1$-axis along the path $(t, 0)$, with $t>0$. At some point you will leave the bidisc, and this will clearly be at the boundary point $(r_1, 0)\in C(0, r_1)\times \Delta(0, r_2)$.

Comment: @PerErikManne so if I understand correctly, there are points on the bidisc which are on the circle $C(0, r_1)$, so on the boundary of $\Delta(0,r_1) $ BUT they are also on the disc $\Delta(0, r_2)$ ? And therefore $C(0,r_1) \times \Delta(0, r_2)$ also makes a part of the boundary of the whole bidisc?

Comment: What you say is basically correct, but note that (i) you have defined the bidisc as an open set, so the boundary points are not part of the bidisc, and (ii) you should be more careful to distinguish between the point $(z_1, z_2)$ of the bidisc and the coordinates $z_1$ and $z_2$.

Comment: @syphracos if you're having trouble understanding why boundary works as I mentioned in my prior comment, think about $A = B = [0,1]$. Then $A \times B$ should be a filled square, so should the (unfilled) square as it's boundary. This is indeed true, since $\partial (A \times B) = (\partial A \times B) \cup (A \times \partial B) = (\{0,1\} \times [0,1]) \cup ([0,1] \times \{0,1\})$ is indeed a square. What you seem to be claiming is that we should have $\partial (A \times B) = \partial A \times \partial B$, which would only yield the four corners of the square.

Comment: Per Erik Manne's comment is basically saying the same phenomonon happens with bidisks. The only difficulty is that it happens in $\mathbb C^2 \cong \mathbb R^4$ so it's harder to visualize.

Comment: Thank You very much to both for clarifying it! I will have to wrap my head around a little bit but like @BrevanEllefsen said, it is harder to visualize it because of the dimensios, so that's where it "stucks" a little bit.